# Итерация по всем точкам внутри GraphicsPath

Tags: c#, graphics, итераторы

Товарищи, возник такой вопрос:
Положим, мы имеем некий `GraphicsPath`. Необходимо каким-то образом *достать* из него все точки с целыми координатами, которые удовлетворяют условию `graphicsPath.IsVisible(x, y)`.
Дабы избежать [проблемы XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy), расскажу, для чего мне это необходимо: с помощью экземпляра `GraphicsPath` я пытаюсь задать множество точек, по которым необходимо пройтись в обрабатываемом мною изображении (а так как координаты каждого из пикселей - число целое, то и выбрать мне нужно лишь точки с целочисленными координатами). 
Пока что у меня в коде висит такой костыльный вариант:

```
Image img = ...;
GraphicsPath path = ...;
for (int y = 0; y < img.Height; y++)
    for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; x++)
        if (path.IsVisible(x, y))
            ...
```

То есть я прохожусь по всем точкам изображения и работаю лишь с теми, что удовлетворяют заданным условиям. Данный метод является совершенно не оптимальным, ибо, предположим, если в `GraphicsPath` содержится всего одна точка, проход по тысячам других точек улетает впустую...
Думаю, в этом вопросе может помочь `GraphicsPathIterator`, который позволяет последовательно пройтись по всем добавленным "фигурам". Право, я все равно пока не совсем представляю алгоритма, который бы позволил мне по точкам контура получить все необходимые мне точки (то есть не только контура, но и те, что внутри него)

---

Буду крайне признателен любым соображениям по сему вопросу. Возможно, есть какие-то более простые пути, чем тот, которым я пытаюсь идти сейчас ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

---

**UPD:**
Попробовал использовать `GraphicsPathIterator` и предложенный метод `GraphicsPath.GetBounds()`. Получилось вот что:

```
public static IEnumerable<Point> GetInnerPoints(this GraphicsPath Path, float Deviation)
{
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.White, Deviation);
    HashSet<Point> points = new HashSet<Point>();
    GraphicsPathIterator iter = new GraphicsPathIterator(Path);
    int length = iter.SubpathCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        GraphicsPath sub = new GraphicsPath();
        iter.NextSubpath(sub, out bool closed);
        RectangleF rect = sub.GetBounds();
        int minX = (int)rect.Left;
        int minY = (int)rect.Top;
        int maxX = (int)Math.Ceiling(rect.Right) + 1;
        int maxY = (int)Math.Ceiling(rect.Bottom) + 1;
        for (int y = minY; y < maxY; y++)
            for (int x = minX; x < maxX; x++)
                if (sub.IsVisible(x, y) || sub.IsOutlineVisible(x, y, pen))
                {
                    Point current = new Point(x, y);
                    if (!points.Contains(current))
                    {
                        points.Add(current);
                        yield return current;
                    }
                }
    }
}
public static IEnumerable<Point> GetInnerPoints(this GraphicsPath Path)
{
    return GetInnerPoints(Path, 0.1f);
}
```

Собственно, логика такова: я прохожусь по всем `Subpath` в данном `GraphicsPath`, исследуя лишь используемые ими площади и выцепляя нужные мне точки с целочисленными координатами. Сие работает вроде бы как надо, правда, подозреваю, можно все таки сделать лучше и куда oптимальнее ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

---

**UPD2:**
Пришел к выводу, что сей метод слишком медленный. К примеру, если в `GraphicsPath` добавить `Rectangle`, равный площади всего изображения, то метод работает в сотни раз медленнее, чем просто обработка всего изображения ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Как простейшую оптимизацию можно проходить только по точкам внутри `path.GetBounds()`. Однако, этот прямоугольник может быть равен всему изображению, тогда это не даст выгоды.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, обновил вопрос с использованием предложенного Вами метода)